# How to set the build variant programmatically at runtime in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, build-variant

Is it possible to change the build variant Programmatically run time in Android Studio?

I have different server environments (Release, Debug, Production, Dev, Dev1, Dev2, QA, etc.). The code itself relies on some strings, SDK's initialization, and server addresses that are set when I pick my build variant. So when I pick debug for an instance, the string uses out debug server address and SDK's. The same for release.  But what if I want to be able to pick the environment during run-time?

Comment: have you tried using productFlavors in gradle files ?. Using flavors you can choose the type of app you want to run at build time. Along with that you can add specific string that will run only with that vairent

Answer (score 3):

Build variants are a build time process, meaning if you want to change the build variant of your apk then you will have to rebuild your project. I see you require something which is equivalent to `setting.bundles` which is the concept of iOS. Android doesn't have such concepts although we can implement it by using `Preference` or using [managed-configuration](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) in all these implementations you will have to clear app cache. I would recommend to create a generic build variant with all specified URLs and handle the configurations at the run time

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the name "**build** variant" it is used while **building** and not while **running**. 
You cannot change the build variant at runtime.
You have to come up with another aproach like a hidden debug view to change your parameters at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> No,You can only change it run time.

Alternatively, You can create a **singleton** for variant class and create a list of variants.Select the variant from a view and store it in cache and when app runs you can get that variant.Restart your application

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom POJO class for your Variants and try to save the desired Variant in shared preferences and then simple restart your android application. Load value in the Singelton Variant object from the cache and do whatever you want to do with your app.