# How to change Build variant Programatically in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, build-variant

I am making an application in Kotlin where, there is a dropDown menu with my pre-made build variant like QA, PROD & DEBUG.

I want to change my build variant based on a selection from DropDown.

**Due to some restrictions, I can't share my code. Any link for a sample would be appreciable**

Comment: You can check on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430212/how-to-set-the-build-variant-programmatically-at-runtime-in-android-studio

Comment: Define "programatically"... Did you mean from command line?(check gradle documentation) or inside android app(not possible)?

Comment: @Selvin means I want to perform an app like QA or debug selection behavior. when the user selects menu from drop down.

Comment: make 4th app which would run one of the other 3 app .. as obviously 3 build variant creates 3 different apps - (but each variant should have different app id)